# React hooks router is not rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Im trying to lazy load my components with react-router. But component is not rendering after redirect. I have to refresh page manually to see the component. Where is my fault ?

routes.js ;

```
import React from "react";
const Bank = React.lazy(() => import("containers/HomePage"));
const MoneyWithdraw = React.lazy(() => import("containers/Withdraw"));

const routes = [
  { path: "/main", exact: true, component: Bank },
  { path: "/withdraw", exact: true, component: MoneyWithdraw },
];

export default routes;
```

index.js ;

```
<div
  hidden={process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? !hidden : hidden}
  className={hidden ? 'app-show' : 'app-hide'}>
  <Suspense fallback={<div>test</div>}>
    <Router history={history}>
    <MenuSideBar />
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, idx) => {
          return route.component ? (
            <Route
              key={idx}
              path={route.path}
              exact={route.exact}
              render={props => <route.component {...props} />}
            />
          ) : null;
        })}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Suspense>
</div>
```

I used history as ;

```
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
export default createHashHistory();
```

Comment: I fixed it by downgrading history version from 5 to 4. Problem was history.